# Isomorphism between $V^* \otimes V$ and $\operatorname{End} V$

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products, vector-space-isomorphism

If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $\operatorname{End} V$ is the set of endomorphisms from $V$ to $V$.

Defining a map from $V^*\otimes V\rightarrow \operatorname{End} V$ by sending some element say, $f\otimes v \in V^* \otimes V$ to endomorphism whose value at $w\in V$ is $f(w)v$.

I am trying to show this map is an isomorphism between $V^* \otimes V$ and $\operatorname{End} V$. I am trying to verify it using dual basis.

If some hint can be provided, it will be a great help!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: HInt: look at $f \mapsto f_i^je^i\otimes e_j$ where $(f^j_i)$ is the matrix of $f$ in the basis $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$, and $(e^1,\ldots,e^n)$ is the dual basis.

Comment: Without addition restrictions, the claim in question is false: Any endomorphism obtained form this map will only have finite-dimensional image. In particular, for infinite-dimensional $V$, you cannot even obtain the identity endomorphism. -- Given this restriction, it seems natural to pick a basis of $V$ (and of $V^*$) and work with that

Comment: As Hagen says, The vector space $V$ must be finite dimensional (otherwise, your claim is false). Observe that both spaces have dimension $\dim (V)^2$ and thus you only have to check that your map is a monomorphism or an epimorphism.

Comment: @guidoar That's of course even better. One should avoid working with a basis as much as possible, and then some.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen about the same time you responded I erased my last remark. I still *think* we should get away with a coordinate-free argument, but on my way writing I figured out I actually hadn't one in mind.

Comment: @Didier I got that. Indirectly, you are basically sending matrix say $A$ of $f$ to matrix $A^T$. Clearly, it follows. thanks!

Comment: @Hagen Von Eitzen I edited my question. Thanks!